# How to spoof a click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, lightbox, spoof

I want to try and find a way to spoof a click with jQuery/Javascript.

Basically I have an image wrapped in an  tag. When I click this I want the browser to think it has clicked a different  link and run that instead.

I have lightbox activated on the click of $('.gallery a') I want to click one image but have lightbox think I've clicked another and open that up in the lightbox instead.

Answer (score 1):

just do `$('#selector').click()`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this.

```
$('.gallery a').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the click event.

in this case

```
$(".gallery a").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
event.preventDefault();
$("other_link").trigger("click");
```